# React child component not re-rendering on parent force update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing a problem where calling forceUpdate on parent component doesn't re render the child component. I have attached the code snippets below.

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
    const forceUpdate = React.useReducer(() => ({}))[1];

    const getAccountDetails = () => {
    const opts = {
        mailboxKey: details.getMailboxKey()
    };
    details.getAccountDetails(opts).then((response) => {
        if (response.resp.data.lastSyncTime && response.resp.data.lastSyncTime !== -1) {
            setLastSyncTime(response.resp.data.lastSyncTime);
            if (response?.resp?.data?.ssi) {
                details.set("ssi", response.resp.data.ssi);
            }
            if (response?.resp?.data?.fsi) {
                details.set("fsi", response.resp.data.fsi);
            }
        }
        details.set("isSyncCompleted", response.resp.data?.isSyncCompleted);
    }).catch((ex) => {
        succErrMsg(getI18N("ERROR"), {
            severity: "error",
            ...succErrMsgOption
        });
    });
    forceUpdate();
};

useEffect(() => {
    getAccountDetails();
}, []);

const renderStatustable = () => {
    const isSyncCompleted = details.getIsSyncCompleted();
    if (isSyncCompleted) {
        return <ImapSyncStatus {...{details}} />;
    }
    return <ImapFolderSyncStatus {...{details, getAccountDetails}} />;
};
return (showSyncStatusTable && renderStatustable())
```

**CHILD COMPONENT ImapFolderSyncStatus.js**

```
const [fsiData, setFsiData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    setFsiData(details.getFolderSyncStatusInfo());
}, []);

function renderFolderSyncStatusRows () {
    const rows = [];
    for (const key in fsiData) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(fsiData, key)) {
            const element = fsiData[key];
            rows.push(
                <Tr>
                    <Td>
                        {element.folderName}
                    </Td>
                    <Td>
                        {element.ci.ZCount}
                    </Td>
                    <Td>
                        {element.ci.mailCount}
                    </Td>
                </Tr>
            );
        }
    }
    return rows;
}

    return (<>
<ButtonColumn align="right">
                            <Button variant="flat" variantColor="primary" size="custom" onClick={getAccountDetails}>
                                <Icon className="rotate-right" />
                                {getI18N("Refresh folder")}
                            </Button>
                        </ButtonColumn>{renderFolderSyncStatusRows()}
</>);
```

As u can see, I am calling the parent *getAccountDetails* function from child. The function gets called correctly and forceUpdate is also triggered. However if I add breakpoint on the line *const [fsiData, setFsiData] = useState();* and inside the useEffect in child component, only the former breakpoint is triggered. I solved this by adding a key to the child component but I don't understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: If you need a `forceUpdate` function, your app is broken in some way, and will likely contain subtle, hard-to-debug bugs.

Comment: Yeah. Like I mentioned the fix is to add a unique key to the child component and it fixes the issue without forceUpdate. But I like to know why forceUpdate not rerendering. I guess it has to do something with object. But don't know exactly.

Comment: Well, see my answer. It explains what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your child component is updating just fine. It's just that the data you're seeing won't because of your misuse of `useEffect`.

With a component like

```
function Component(...) {
  const [fsiData, setFsiData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFsiData(details.getFolderSyncStatusInfo());
  }, []);
  // ... use fsiData for rendering...
}
```

the effect is only ever run when the component mounts and never again.

The props changing doesn't cause the component to (re)mount, so the effect is never run and you're stuck with the same data. (The component's `key` changing will cause a remount.)

Just do

```
function Component(...) {
  const fsiData = details.getFolderSyncStatusInfo();
}
```